# Plot ramp pulse function in Python

Tags: python, plot, signals

I have to solve this exercise and don't really know what to change in my code in order to get the ramp on the interval [3,4], since I'm very new to Python. Here is the actual problem:

x(A, t1, t2, t) = A/(t2 - t1) * (t - t1) if t1 <= t < t2       AND        0 otherwise

Test by plotting the values and the envelope of myRampPulse for a signal with amplitude 1,
starting in second 3 and ending in second 4, for a sampling with frequency 20 Hz, started in second
0 and ended in second 5.

I've pasted my code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


A = 1       # amplitude
t1 = 3      # start time
t2 = 4      # stop time
fs = 20     # sampling frequency

t = np.arange(0, 5, 1/fs)

def myRampPulse(A, t1, t2, t):
    while(len(t)):
        return (A*((t>=t1)&(t<t2)))

result = myRampPulse(A, t1, t2, t)

plt.close('all')
plt.plot(t, result, '.')
plt.axis([0, 5, -2, 2])       
plt.title('Ramp pulse signal')
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your myRampPulse() function with this

```
def myRampPulse(A, t1, t2, t):
    while(len(t)):
        return (A*((t>=t1)&(t<t2))) * (t-t1) / (t2-t1)
```